# Duplicate URL 301-redirection: why not 308?

Tags: seo, 301-redirect

I avoid Google's complaints about duplicates by using a 301 redirect, according to numerous tips here and on the net.
However, I'm curious as to why it's appropriate to use a 301 code rather than a 308 code. I found this note in MMDN regarding 308:

> The request method and the body will not be altered, whereas 301 may
> incorrectly sometimes be changed to a GET method.

Is there a simple general justification for 301 vs. 308?

Comment: This is an interesting question - I'd not heard of a 308 redirect before.  After reading up on this a bit I posit that 301's are better established/well known because it confirms to an older standard - ie  RFC2616 did not have a reference to it, but RFC7231 (and RFC 9110) does.   If you are not worried about passing parameters it doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As davidgo mentions in the comments, the main reasons are "established convention" and backward compatibility.

The 308 (Permanent Redirect) was [introduced in RFC-7238](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7238) in 2014, while 301, 302 have been around since at least 1997 (and 307 was introduced in 1999).

The introduction for RFC-7238 states:

> [T]he status codes 301 (Moved Permanently), 302 (Found), and 307 (Temporary Redirect), which can be classified as below:

| Notes | Permanent | Temporary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Allows changing the request method from `POST` to `GET` | 301 | 302 |
| Does not allow changing the request `POST` to `GET` | - | 307 |

As you can see, the key reason for introducing the 308 was to allow for clients to perform a permanent redirect *while requiring the client to maintain the original method* - i.e. in the case of a form submission (or API call), the calling client should:

1. Reissue the request, unmodified, along with all data to the new URL defined in the `location` response header.
2. Update any "bookmarks" to point to the new location going forward.

If you issue a `301` redirect, most clients will just perform a `GET` on the URL, even if the original request was a POST - whether this is the desired behaviour for your application is something for you to decide.

Comment: Does it mean that in my case (redirection of url "duplicates" claimed by Google) I could use 308 just as well, or even better??

Comment: In general, the duplicates crawled by Google will have been requested via a `GET` request, so those would be fine to handle with a 301. GoogleBot will happily respect a 308 correctly, as will all modern browsers - so if you want to simply issue those as 308 that will be fine.